# XSLT misunderstanding document() function

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'am trying to combine 2 xml documents, taking some attribute values in the first one and injecting it in the other.

My first xml : Manual.xml has this form : I have something like 5 000 tasks as the following :

```
           <task chapnbr="05"
                 sectnbr="11"
                 subjnbr="04"
                 pgblknbr="08"
                 breaknbr="001"
                 confnbr=""
                 confgtxt=""
                 func="200"
                 seq="001"
                 confltr=""
                 chg="u"
                 key="t051104200001"
                 revdate="20070615">
              <effect effrg="ALL">
```

The second xml I handle : Dictionary.xml :

```
<dictionary engine="CFM56" version="3" manual="ESM">
   <task oldkey="T050000870001"
         newkey="TKESM050000870001"
         chapnbr="05"
         sectnbr="00"
         subjnbr="00"
         func="870"
         seq="001">
      <title>GENERAL - INTRODUCTION</title>
   </task>
   <task oldkey="T051100200001"
         newkey="TKESM051100200001"
         chapnbr="05"
         sectnbr="11"
         subjnbr="00"
         func="200"
         seq="001">
      <title>LIFE LIMITS OF ENGINE ROTATING PARTS</title>
   </task>
   <task oldkey="T051101200001"
         newkey="TKESM051101200001"
         chapnbr="05"
         sectnbr="11"
         subjnbr="01"
         func="200"
         seq="001">
      <title>FAN ROTOR - LIFE LIMITS</title>
   </task>
   <task oldkey="T051102200001"
         newkey="TKESM051102200001"
         chapnbr="05"
         sectnbr="11"
         subjnbr="02"
         func="200"
         seq="001">
      <title>HIGH PRESSURE COMPRESSOR ROTOR - LIFE LIMITS</title>
</dictionary>
```

I need to take the value of the attribute "seq" in the Dictionary and replace it in the Manual if the attribute "oldkey" in the Dictionary is equal to the attribute "key" in the Manual.

To do that i have wrote this XSLT :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">

<xsl:output 
    encoding="UTF-8"
    method="xml" 
    indent="yes" 
    omit-xml-declaration="yes" 
    cdata-section-elements="comments"/>


<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@seq[parent::task]">
    <xsl:variable name="oldkey" select="upper-case(../@key)"/>
    <xsl:attribute name="seq">
        <xsl:value-of select="document('./Dictionary.xml')/dictionary/task[@oldkey=$oldkey]/@seq"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>  

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But the result i obtain is that all the values of "seq" are changed and replaced by a blank in the Manual. Here an example of output :

```
<task chapnbr="72"
                 sectnbr="00"
                 subjnbr="00"
                 pgblknbr="01"
                 breaknbr="011"
                 confnbr=""
                 confgtxt=""
                 func="810"
                 seq=""
                 confltr=""
                 chg="u"
                 key="t720000810011"
                 revdate="19981015">
```

I guess my problem comes from the way i use the document() function but I have tried many things and nothing changes. The result is allaways the same, I don't manage to obtain another value except a blank in the attribute "seq" of my output file Manual.

I need to obtain an ouput where the attribute "seq" value is made of 3 integers and read from the Dictionnary. Something likes that :

```
<task chapnbr="72"
                 sectnbr="00"
                 subjnbr="00"
                 pgblknbr="01"
                 breaknbr="011"
                 confnbr=""
                 confgtxt=""
                 func="810"
                 seq="001"
                 confltr=""
                 chg="u"
                 key="t720000810011"
                 revdate="19981015">
```

To be more accurate about my input/outuput file (Manual.xml). The complete file is of the following form :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE EM [<!ENTITY g1105335-00 SYSTEM " file://D:/Indigo_AP/Load_CFM56-3/5-   Inputs/../Arts/1105335-00.tif" NDATA ccitt4>
<!ENTITY g1105336-00 SYSTEM " file://D:/Indigo_AP/Load_CFM56-3/5-Inputs/../Arts/1105336-00.tif" NDATA ccitt4 >

<!-- A lot of Doctype declaration -->

<em spl="062W0"
model="CFM56-3"
oidate="19831231"
tsn="71"
docnbr="CFMI-TP_SM_5"
lang="english"
revdate="20131215"
chg="u">
   <title>CFM56-3 Engine Manual</title>

   <!-- Many child elements -->

   <chapter chapnbr="05" chg="u" key="c05" revdate="20121215">
      <title>TIME LIMITS AND MAINTENANCE CHECKS</title>

      <section chapnbr="05"
           sectnbr="00"
           chg="u"
           key="cs0500"
           revdate="20121215">
         <title>GENERAL</title>

         <subject chapnbr="05"
              sectnbr="00"
              subjnbr="00"
              chg="u"
              key="css050000"
              revdate="20121215">
            <title>GENERAL - INTRODUCTION</title>

            <pgblk chapnbr="05"
               sectnbr="00"
               subjnbr="00"
               pgblknbr="00"
               breaknbr="001"
               chg="u"
               key="p05000000001000"
               revdate="20121215">
              <title>GENERAL - INTRODUCTION</title>

               <task chapnbr="05"
                 sectnbr="00"
                 subjnbr="00"
                 pgblknbr="00"
                 breaknbr="001"
                 confnbr=""
                 confgtxt=""
                 func="870"
                 seq="001"
                 confltr=""
                 chg="u"
                 key="t050000870001"
                 revdate="20121215">
                  <effect effrg="ALL"></effect>
                  <title>GENERAL - INTRODUCTION</title>

                  <!-- Many child elements -->

           </task>
        </pgblk>
     </subject>
  </section>

  <section chapnbr="05"
           sectnbr="11"
           chg="u"
           key="cs0511"
           revdate="20121215">
     <title>LIFE LIMITS</title>

     <subject chapnbr="05"
              sectnbr="11"
              subjnbr="00"
              chg="u"
              key="css051100"
              revdate="20070615">
        <title>LIFE LIMITS</title>

        <pgblk chapnbr="05"
               sectnbr="11"
               subjnbr="00"
               pgblknbr="08"
               breaknbr="001"
               chg="u"
               key="p05110008001000"
               revdate="20070615">
           <title>LIFE LIMITS OF ENGINE ROTATING PARTS</title>

           <task chapnbr="05"
                 sectnbr="11"
                 subjnbr="00"
                 pgblknbr="08"
                 breaknbr="001"
                 confnbr=""
                 confgtxt=""
                 func="200"
                 seq="001"
                 confltr=""
                 chg="u"
                 key="t051100200001"
                 revdate="20070615">
              <effect effrg="ALL"></effect>
              <title>LIFE LIMITS OF ENGINE ROTATING PARTS</title>

              <!-- Many child elements -->

           </task>
        </pgblk>
     </subject>

     <subject chapnbr="05"
              sectnbr="11"
              subjnbr="01"
              chg="u"
              key="css051101"
              revdate="20070615">
        <title>FAN ROTOR - LIFE LIMITS</title>

        <pgblk chapnbr="05"
               sectnbr="11"
               subjnbr="01"
               pgblknbr="08"
               breaknbr="001"
               chg="u"
               key="p05110108001000"
               revdate="20070615">
           <title>FAN ROTOR - LIFE LIMITS</title>

           <task chapnbr="05"
                 sectnbr="11"
                 subjnbr="01"
                 pgblknbr="08"
                 breaknbr="001"
                 confnbr=""
                 confgtxt=""
                 func="200"
                 seq="001"
                 confltr=""
                 chg="u"
                 key="t051101200001"
                 revdate="20070615">
              <effect effrg="ALL"></effect>
              <title>FAN ROTOR - LIFE LIMITS</title>

              <!-- Many child elements -->

               </task>
            </pgblk>
         </subject>
      </section>
   </chapter>
</em>
```

Comment: Please post minimal but **complete** examples of your input and of the expected output. Currently both your input documents are not well-formed XML.

Comment: My inputs and output are made of more than two million lines, that's why i posted only samples.

Comment: Samples are ok, but they need to be well-formed.

Comment: Is there perhaps a namespace used in the second XML? If nothing is selected then often namespaces are the reason.

Comment: Hi Martin. No, both inputs (Manual and Dictionary) don't use any namespace.

Comment: @Charpi, consider to post small but complete samples allowing us to reproduce the problem. Currently it looks like your template is used but somehow no value is found in the other document. If namespaces are not the reason then I am not sure what is, if you provide something for us to test and work with then I am sure we can resolve it.

Comment: I think it's quite clear that your expression `document('./Dictionary.xml')/dictionary/task[@oldkey=$oldkey]/@seq` does not select anything. So either (a) the document is not where you think it is; or (b) the structure of the document is not what you think it is; or (c) the keys do not match (or any combination thereof). --- Unrelated to your current issue, but you should be using a **key** to retrieve the value, esp. if your documents are so large..

Comment: @michael.hor257k Yes my problem comes from the expression document(). (a) Do you agree if I use the expresssion './Dictionary.xml' to call the file, the file has to be in the same directory as the XSL file ?   (b) I have checked once more the structure of my document but i still don't see where i'm wrong. I have edited my question and posted the complete input/output file, if you want take a look.  (c) Trying to use a key is a good lead, i'll study that and then let you know my results. Thank you for the proposals.

Comment: (a) Yes.  'Dictionary.xml' would be also sufficient. (b) The structure of the Dictionary document posted here is not well-formed (missing closing tags).

Comment: Oups sorry for the Dictionnary i forgot the closing tags. I edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you run the following stylesheet (against any well-formed XML input) and see what you get:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="dict" select="document('Dictionary.xml')" />
<xsl:variable name="key" select="'T050000870001'" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <results>
        <dictionary-exists>
            <xsl:value-of select="boolean($dict)"/>
        </dictionary-exists>
        <entry-exists>
            <xsl:value-of select="boolean($dict/dictionary/task[@oldkey=$key])"/>
        </entry-exists>
        <value>
            <xsl:value-of select="$dict/dictionary/task[@oldkey=$key]/@seq"/>
        </value>
    </results>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I get this output : `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results>
   <dictionary-exists>false</dictionary-exists>
   <entry-exists>false</entry-exists>
   <value/>
</results>` The problem seems to be that the xsl processor isn't able to find the Dictionary file, but i checked twice and the Dictionary file is in the same directory as my xsl file

Comment: Well, at least you know where the problem is now. Perhaps check the file's name for leading/trailing spaces and other anomalies like that.

Comment: I checked again the file's name but nothing seems wrong. I found this disccusion on sourceforge : [link here](http://sourceforge.net/p/saxon/mailman/saxon-help/thread/t23a8u00fhanait49o53e4fgj8hfaka6ud@4ax.com/) .And i'm using saxon transformer. Maybe my problem is due to the way my transformer handles the xsl file

Comment: I've had an error handling on my class which implements URIResolver and i get this error message : `Error Document has been marked not available: file:/D:/Appl/Opt/Eclipse_Workspace/IndigoInitialLoading/xsl/ata/Dictionary; SystemID: file:/D:/Appl/Opt/Eclipse_Workspace/IndigoInitialLoading/xsl/ata/ChangeSeq.xsl; Line#: 6; Column#: -1
` The SystemID that identifies my xsl file and the path to the Dictionay.xml are ok but i get this message `Error Document has been marked not available`

Comment: Doesn't sound like the problem is in the realm of XSLT. I suggest you post a separate question (using the simplified scenario above).

Comment: Anyway, I can't spend more time on this problem, I'll change my design and do all the process in pure java. It will be a litlle heavy and dirty but I don't see other solution. Thank you for spending time on my problem and helping to find the orginin of my bug. I mark this answer as the most useful. If I have time I'll study later how works the java file ID system, I guess the breakdown is here.